# How to call Primefaces JavaScript function after pageload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces, wizard

I am using custom buttons for **PrimefaceWizard** and remove default navigation buttons from Primeface Wizard by adding the attribute `showNavBar="false"` .

```
<p:wizard style="border:0" showNavBar="false" widgetVar="terminationWizard"  onback="if (PF('terminationWizard').getStepIndex(PF('terminationWizard').currentStep) === 0) { PF('stepBackward').disable(); } PF('stepForward').enable();"
 onnext="if (PF('terminationWizard').getStepIndex(PF('terminationWizard').currentStep) === 1) { PF('stepForward').disable(); } PF('stepBackward').enable();" >
```

Buttons code

```
<p:commandButton widgetVar="stepBackward" value="Back"  
 onclick="PF('terminationWizard').back()" />

<p:commandButton value="Next"  onclick="PF('terminationWizard').next();" widgetVar="stepForward"/>
```

But issue is that when Wizard page loading it showing Back button in first tab which i will want to disable or remove from the page when i am in first tab.  Tried to add jquery like this

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        PF('terminationWizard').hideBackNav();
    });
</script>
```

But it is not working. Can any one please tell me what other way to do it.

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar I want to remove/diable Back button when its in first tab same as primefaces demo wizard working http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/wizard.xhtml

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar I remove default button and added custom button you can check `showNavBar="false"`

Answer (score -1):

```
Maybe a small delay will solve the problem :

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
           PF('terminationWizard').hideBackNav();
        }, 700);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: this won't do since he is using a custom nav buttons